# ssh client to show server-supported algorithms

Tags: go, ssh, cryptography

In order to check that all the servers across a fleet aren't supporting deprecated algorithms, I'm (programmatically) doing this:

```
telnet localhost 22 
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost. 
Escape character is '^]'. 
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1
SSH-2.0-Censor-SSH2 
4&m����&F �V��curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1Arsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519lchacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.comlchacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com�umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1�umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1none,zlib@openssh.comnone,zlib@openssh.comSSH-2.0-Censor-SSH2
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Which is supposed to be a list of supported algorithms for the various phases of setting up a connection. (kex, host key, etc).   Every time I run, I get a different piece of odd data at the start - always a different length.

There's an nmap plugin - ssh2-enum-algos - which returns the data in it's complete form, but I don't want to run nmap; I have a go program which opens the port, and sends the query, but it gets the same as telnet.      What am I missing, and how do I fix it?

For comparison, here's the top few lines from the output of nmap script:

```
$ nmap --script ssh2-enum-algos super
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-27 22:15 GMT
Nmap scan report for super (192.168.50.1)
Host is up (0.0051s latency).
rDNS record for 192.168.50.1: supermaster
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
| ssh2-enum-algos: 
|   kex_algorithms: (12)
|       curve25519-sha256
|       curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp256
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp384
|       ecdh-sha2-nistp521
```

Comment: Running "ssh -Q <cipher_use_case>"  is useful for finding the algorithms supported by the client - I need to ensure that the server isn't offering the use of deprecated algorithms.

Comment: Your data is odd because SSH is not a text protocol, it's a binary one, and the telnet command knows nothing at all about it. Nmap, on the other hand, does now something about the SSH protocol. Just because you see some recognizable ASCII strings in a protocol does not necessarily mean it's a text-based protocol.

Comment: What does telnet need to know?  Surely before the client and server are able to set up an encrypted (binary) connection, they negotiate in "ASCII" (I put that in quotes because I'd only expect the algorithm names to be ASCII).  Running the nmap script with --script-trace it showing similar data to the "binary" format I get from telnet, yet nmap is able to produce useful output. So I agree that nmap knows something I don't - that was sort of my question, really.

Comment: The protocol is documented in [RFC 4253](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253) -- and don't call me Shirley. The first 3 lines of output (`Trying 127.0.0.1...`, etc) have nothing to do with the protocol, that's just the telnet program reporting its progress. The next two are an exchange of ASCII version information. After that, the binary protocol occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a tcp connection to port 22, (in golang, with net.Dial) then accepting and sending connection strings leaves us able to Read() from the Reader for the connection.  Thence the data is in a standard format described by the RFC.  From this, I can list the algorithms supported in each phase of an ssh connection.   This is very useful for measuring what is being offered, rather than what the appears to be configured (it's easy to configure sshd to use a different config file).

It's a useful thing to be able to do from a security POV.
Tested on every version of ssh I can find from 1.x on a very old solaris or AIX box, to RHEL 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can specify an algorithm to use, and if you specify one that is not supported the server will reply with a list of supported algorithms.

For example, to check for supported key exchange algorithms you can use:

```
ssh 127.0.0.1 -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 is insecure and should be missing from most modern servers. The server will probably respond with something like:

```
Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
Exit 255
```

Typing: "ssh -Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key"
will give you a list of the algorithms supported by your client

Typing: "man ssh"
will let you see what options you can specify with the -o argument, including  Cipher, MACs, and KexAlgorithms